# How do I create a method that makes an object move

Tags: processing

I'm trying to create a method in Processing that moves a ball around the screen. However, the ball won't move when I press keys, however in the theory it should. What am I doing wrong?

```java
float x = 100;
float y = 100;
void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
}
void draw() {
  fill(0);
  ellipse(x, y, 10, 10);
  move();
}
void reset() {
  x = height/2;
  y = width/2;
}
void move() {
  if (keyPressed == true) {
    if (key == 'a') {
      x = x - 3;
    } else if (key == 's') {
      y = y + 3;
    } else if (key == 'd') {
      x = x + 3;
    } else if (key == 'w') {
      y = y + 3;
    } else if (key == ' ') {
      reset();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: may be you need to `draw()` once you update the coordinates?

Comment: @mustaccio Processing automatically calls the `draw()` function.

Comment: How can I fix this? Putting draw at the end did not help

Comment: I can't see where keyPressed is becoming true in the code.

Comment: @ZayedUpal Processing automatically sets the `keyPressed` variable.

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code, I do see the circle move. You've just got two issues:

First, you aren't clearing out old frames, so instead of just seeing a ball, you see a trail in all of the ball's previous locations. To fix this, you could call the `background()` function every frame.

Secondly, you're doing the same thing when the user presses both the `w` and `s` keys. So the ball goes down in both cases. You can fix this by changing your logic in the `w` case.